# Crime-fighting insomniac who wears a bullet-proof trenchcoat

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this movie a long time ago, sometime in the 90s.

All I can remember clearly about it is that this guy is an insomniac and never sleeps but at night he goes out and fights crime in some way or form. I clearly remember something about a trenchcoat he wears that is bullet proof and he used it to protect a child at one point. He also swapped it for a new one at a shop in one scene.

Does anybody know what film this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["The Owl"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102618/) from 1991 stars Adrian Paul as an insomniac vigilante wearing a kevlar trench coat. Basically an unpicked TV pilot, it was also called "Night Owl". From IMDb:

> Alex L'Hiboux, a ruthless mercenary-cum-vigilante, is known as 'the Owl' because he never sleeps. His insomnia comes from a combination of a medical disorder and recurring nightmares of the murder of his wife and daughter. Alex is approached by Lisa, a young girl whose father is missing. She awakens painful memories of his own child, but after some persuasion from a policewoman friend, he agrees to help her.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Taxi Driver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075314/). Travis Bickle works at night. Fantasizes about cleaning up the streets. He protects Jodie Foster's character. However The bullet proof coat doesn't fit.

Comment: Unfortunately not Taxi Driver.